# Continuity proof over the rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function with domain $(a, b)$. Show that if $f(r) = 0$ for each rational number $r$ in $(a, b)$, then $f(x) = 0$ $\forall x \in (a, b)$.

Here's my proof (can someone please verify it?):

Suppose $\exists k \in \mathbb{Q}^c \cap (a, b)$, such that $f(k) = \alpha \neq 0$.

Let $\epsilon = \displaystyle{\frac{|\alpha|}{2}}$, and $\delta > 0$. Due to the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we can find a rational number $q \in (a, b) \cap (k - \delta, k + \delta)$ such that $f(q)=0$. But then, $|f(q) - f(k)| = |\alpha| > \epsilon$. This would imply that $f$ is discontinuous, a contradiction. Therefore, it must be the case that $f(x) = 0 \ \forall x \in (a, b)$

Answer (score 2):

You proof is correct. Alternatively, you could use the density of $\mathbb{Q} \cap (a,b)$ in $(a,b)$ to construct a sequence $(x_k)_k$ in $\mathbb{Q} \cap (a,b)$ converging to $x \in (a,b)$ arbitrary.

It follows $f(x) = \lim_k f(x_k) = 0$.